# Creating Internal Table in Amazon Athena

Tags: amazon-s3, ddl, amazon-athena

I'm trying to create an internal table in Athena, on data in S3 in parquet format:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `vdp_dev.owners_daily`(

  `owner_id` string COMMENT 'from deserializer',
  `username` string COMMENT 'from deserializer',
  `billing_with` string COMMENT 'from deserializer',
  `billing_contacts` string COMMENT 'from deserializer',
  `error_code` string COMMENT 'from deserializer')

PARTITIONED BY (
  `dt` string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe'
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  's3://xxxxx-xx-xxxx-xxxxxx/dim/daily/owners';
```

but getting the following error:

> Only external table creation is supported. (Service: AmazonAthena;
>   Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidRequestException; Request ID:
>   13c5325b-2217-4989-b5f3-e717462329c1)

Does someone know why it happens?
Why can't I create an internal table in Athena?

Answer (score 5):

From the Athena [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/creating-tables.html) :

**All Tables Are EXTERNAL**
If you use CREATE TABLE without the EXTERNAL keyword, Athena issues an error; only tables with the EXTERNAL keyword can be created. We recommend that you always use the EXTERNAL keyword. When you drop a table in Athena, only the table metadata is removed; the data remains in Amazon S3.

Comment: Thank you, considering our use case we need to create an internal table.

Comment: AWS Athena just wanted to be too safe about deleting the data while dropping the table. Hence this exception. You can also look at CTAS if that can meet your requirement.  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/ctas-examples.html